# Is the union of $\emptyset$ with another set, $A$ say, disjoint? Even though $\emptyset \subseteq A$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is the union of $\emptyset$ with another set, $A$ say, disjoint?  Even though $\emptyset \subseteq A$?

I would say, yes - vacuously.  But some confirmation would be great.

Comment: Confirmed! Empty set is disjoint from any set.

Comment: Indeed, the empty set is the only disjoint subset of $A$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two sets $A, B$ are disjoint iff $A \cap B = \emptyset$.
You have $A \cap \emptyset = \emptyset$. Therefore $A$ and $\emptyset$ are disjoint.

Answer (score 3):

It might depend on what you mean by disjoint. I would say that the following definition is reasonable.

> **Definition.** Sets $A$ and $B$ are *disjoint* if $A \cap B = \emptyset$.

The set $B = \emptyset$ satisfies this, so $A$ and $\emptyset$ are disjoint. But I would not say that this is true vacuously.

Comment: Since there is no element in the empty set, there is no element in it that can be contained in any other set.  Doesn't this imply vacuously true? I.e. there's nothing in the $\emptyset$ to compare with elements of other sets.

Comment: Alright, but then you're using the following definition. Sets $A$ and $B$ are disjoint if every element of $A$ is not in $B$. I would say this is a clumsy definition because it is not immediately obvious that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint if and only if $B$ and $A$ are disjoint, but sure, in that case, this is vacuously true. Sorry for the misunderstanding

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a disjoint union of two sets.
Two sets are disjoint when their intersection is disjoint.
By thus definition, the empty set and any set are disjoint.
Usually disjoint is limited to not empty sets.

A collection K of sets is collectively disjoint when $\cap$K is empty.
A useful notion of a disjoint collection is pairwise disjoint.
A collection K of sets is pairwise disjoint when $\cap$K is empty.
If K is pairwise disjoint, so is K $\cup$ {empty set}.
Again for this notion, the empty set is usually discarded.

Exercise.  Present a collection of sets that's collectively disjoint but not pairwise disjoint.

Comment: Regarding your first claim: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_union_(topology)

Comment: @Stephen: Wouldnt https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_union have been a more relevant page?

Comment: @celtschk Yes, I'm working on a topological problem, which is why that page came in mind first :)

Comment: @celtschk Using the empty set to form a disjoint union of sets has helped me come to an answer.